# custom admin controller 404

Tags: controllers, magento-1.9.1.1

Here is the config.xml

```
<admin>
    <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                        <args>
                            <modules>
                                <Example_Csfollowup before="Mage_Adminhtml">Example_Csfollowup_Adminhtml</Example_Csfollowup>
                            </modules>
                        </args>
            </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

here is the controllers at app\code\local\Example\Csfollowup\controllers\Adminhtml\CustomController.php

```
class Example_Csfollowup_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        echo 'abc';

        //$this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function listAction()
    {

    }
}
```

but when i visit localhost/m1/index.php/admin/custom, it redirect me to 404, anyone know what is the url it should be?

Comment: Please add in config.xml <admin> before <routers>. Do you have acl file?

Comment: admin is exist in my code, just missing in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a menu and add link inside it, Magento admin will check for security key value in URL, if its not correct or missing, it will redirect you to dashboard page.

Add **adminhtml.xml** in your module's `etc` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <csfollowup module="csfollowup">
            <title>CS Follow</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <items module="csfollowup">
                    <title>My Page</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/custom</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </csfollowup>
    </menu>
</config>
```